# Перевернуть сообщения MySql

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка, mysql

Есть код с mysql запросом:

```
<?php
 $q = $db->query("SELECT `message` FROM `auction_chat` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 66");
 while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
  $message = $d['message'];

  echo $message.'<hr />';
 }
?>
```

Всё работает хорошо, сообщения выводятся сортированными (`ORDER BY id DESC`):

```
mess4
mess3
mess2
mess1
```

Но как мне поменять всё местами? **Не через `ORDER BY id ASC`**, а именно в моём цикле, чтобы было так:

```
mess1
mess2
mess3
mess4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php
сначала соберите данные в массив, а дальше используйте эту функцию.
А вообще, используйте MVC.

Comment: @Victor Halauko, ну как бы $d = $db->assoc($q) - это данные в массиве.

Comment: Так работает или нет функция?

Comment: @Victor Halauko, array_reverse заюзал, спасибо! :)

Comment: Ребят, смысл использовать лишнюю функцию для обработки всего массива, если можно собирать данные в массив уже в обратном порядке с помощью [`array_unshift`][1]?

  [1]: php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: Database class уже возвращает массив. Его не собирают. Я сам в первом посте не заметил этого.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
<?php
    $messages = array();
    $q = $db->query("SELECT `message` FROM `auction_chat` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 66");
    while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
        array_unshift($messages, $d['message']);
    }
    echo implode('<hr />', $message);

?>
```

Comment: @Johny, хм, ну а если у меня не только message выбирается? Такое не пойдёт.

Comment: Если у вас не только message собирается, то и ваш пример без переделки работать корректно не будет. Логично?

Что такое ваше `$db->assoc($q)`? Часть какого-то фреймворка? Что там внутри происходит?

Если там происходит непосредственный вызов mysqli_fetch_assoc или подобное, то на его работу, увы, никак не повлиять. Только запрос менять. Либо же сделать, как я предложил: получить весь результат, и проделать с ним необходимую работу.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, есть такая таблица:

```
+-----------+---+
|date       | id|
+-----------+---+
|2014-02-15 | 67|
|2014-02-17 | 86|
|2014-02-18 | 31|
|2014-02-15 | 98|
|2014-02-17 | 44|
|2014-02-15 | 69|
+-----------+---+
```

---

Напишем функцию сортировки по нескольким полям:

```
function msort()
{
  $params = func_get_args();
  $array = array_pop($params);

  if (!is_array($array))
    return false;

  $multisort_params = array();
  foreach ($params as $i => $param) 
  {
    if (is_string($param)) 
    {
      ${"param_$i"} = array();
      foreach ($array as $index => $row) 
      {
        ${"param_$i"}[$index] = $row[$param];
      }
    }
    else 
      ${"param_$i"} = $params[$i];

    $multisort_params[] = &${"param_$i"};
  }
  $multisort_params[] = &$array;

  call_user_func_array("array_multisort", $multisort_params);

  return $array;
}
```

---

Допустим, мы получили данные из таблицы. Теперь отсортируем, как нам надо.
По полю "date" в порядке убывания и полю "id" в порядке возрастания.

```
# ...получаем данные
# данные получены
$d = $db->assoc($q)
# сортируем...
$sorted = (msort('date', SORT_DESC, 'id', SORT_ASC, $d));
# делаем, что хотели с отсортированными данными...
```

---

Вот так выглядят отсортированные данные:

```
+-----------+---+
|date       | id|
+-----------+---+
|2014-02-18 | 31|
|2014-02-17 | 44|
|2014-02-17 | 86|
|2014-02-15 | 67|
|2014-02-15 | 69|
|2014-02-15 | 98|
+-----------+---+
```

Comment: А если серьезно, то намного проще сделать лишний запрос в БД. И не слушайте никого.Поверьте мне,ваши лишние запросы в БД ну ни как не скажутся на производительности мелкого сайта.